# How to select select more than one date from calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am new to wordpress .i m using jQuery UI Widgets plugin to select date from the jquery calendar.but i want to select more than one date in  calendar .can anyone help me how to do it.any other plugins to do that.

Thanks

This my jquery code

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {

           jQuery('#pre-select-dates').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
});
});
```

Can any one help me to do this.....

Answer (score 0):

Highlighted day have 1px yellow border but its hardly visible, so i added red color to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/TfmKJ/

Probably works for you, just you cannot see it. Selected day have class `ui-state-highlight`

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer.can you help me how to implement this in my post in wordpress.